# Is it possible to use my PC line out as my iPhone line in?

Tags: audio, iphone, microphone

I want to use a self made MP3 for my answering machine (iPhone 5 with O2 provider). I tried to find a solution to upload the MP3, but it seems this option is not available for O2.

So I tried to use my speakers, but the quality I get is really bad.

This is why I am trying to attach my PC line out to my iPhone line in. This way I do not loose any quality, at least on my side.

Answer (score 0):

So long as both sides are connected via a mini stereo jack, you should have no problems. Just get a cable with a mini stereo jack male connector on both ends and plug them into the mentioned lines.

It would be possible even if they had different "interfaces". You would have to get an adapter of some kind in that case. Perhaps that is the core of your question? In that case I'm sure that the fellows at Apple store will be happy to assist you.